# Can I copy (verbatim) my own arxiv paper into my thesis?

Tags: phd, thesis, copyright, arxiv

I wrote an arxiv paper during PhD, first author. I have a major chapter in my thesis on that paper and I would like to use the arxiv paper verbatim. Is it OK, to do that? I'm quite unclear about how copyright works with arxiv.

Basically, I want to know if arxiv holds rights to my work. If so, how much.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I include my ArXiv pre-print as a part of the Thesis?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/169632/can-i-include-my-arxiv-pre-print-as-a-part-of-the-thesis) Copyright isn't the relevant issue here: you own the work. It's more about what thesis expectations are in your field.

Comment: (see also other Q&A here about "sandwich thesis" and "stapler thesis")

Comment: The question is same as mine. But doesn't have a proper answer, whether it is doable for arxiv or not. Unfortunately, I'm not familiar with copyright of arxiv papers and couldn't find it.

Comment: There's no "proper answer" because the "proper answer" is it depends on the expectations of your thesis committee. But copyright is not the correct issue to be concerned about. See also https://arxiv.org/help/license

Comment: The thesis committee doesn't care about copyright. It is the journal (in this case, arxiv) that cares about copyright. The thesis committee usually has no knowledge of copyright.

Comment: Arxiv is **not** a journal. And you're right, the thesis committee doesn't care about copyright in this context, which is why copyright is not the part to worry about.

Comment: Basically, I want to know if arxiv holds rights to my work ?

Comment: IIRC, arXiv only holds a perpetual license to distribute what you gave them. You retain copyright. But you need to explore self-plagiarism also. And, you may have other authors to consider as well if you weren't sole author. See: https://arxiv.org/help/submit

Comment: @ProtyushSahu Are you asking how to interpret the license you used (if so, please specify which one you chose) when submitting your work to arXiv? Because you have read it, right?